# how to use a function as parameter in extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have read that is recomended to use functions instead of predicates in the extension methods, so I am trying to do it.

```
public static void Insert<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> paramOC, T NewElement, Func<T, T, bool> condition)
        {
            //code
        }
```

I am trying to use in this way:

```
myOC.Insert(myNewElement, e=>e.Name.CompareTo(myNewElement.Name) > 0));
```

But I get an error that says that the delete System.Func does not take 1 argument.

However, if I use a predicate intead of the function, it works.

What am I missing?

thank so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Func<T,bool>` (which takes one argument and returns `bool`), not `Func<T,T,bool>`

`Predicate<T>` works because it takes one argument and returns `bool`, so it matches with the *lambda expression*.`Func<T,T,bool>` expects two arguments and returns bool which doesn't match with your expression hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Func<T,T,bool>` takes 2 parameters and returns `bool`

You have two choise

1. as Selman22 says change it to `Func<T,bool>`
2. call it as `(e1,e2) => ..`