# How to set many conditions in Func as argument in extesion method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

[I have asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193010/how-to-use-a-function-as-parameter-in-extension-method)

the problem was solved and Works with one condition, but if I try this:

```
myOC.Insert(myNewElement, (x=> x.ID != 1 && x.Name.CompareTo(myString) > 0))
```

In this case I get an error that says that the delegate Function does not take 1 argument.

My Extension method is:

```
public static void Insert<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> paramOC, T paramNewElement, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    //Code
}
```

How can I set many conditions in the funcion?

thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure? It must work IMO.

Comment: There shouldn't be any compiler errors with what you've shown. Please post the relevant source.

Comment: No, you don't https://ideone.com/b43JGu .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
myOC.Insert(myNewElement, (x=> x.ID != 1 && (x.Name.CompareTo(myString) > 0)))
```

Comment: I have tried this option but don't compile. But thanks for the suggestion.